# Redirecting a specific URL in the htaccess without using a redirect statuscode. Is it possible?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a client that has a website with a homepage set-up like this: https://www.website.com/homepage. I have requested the homepage to be changed to the root domain, like most websites have, but the developer says it's not possible.

I'm not 100% sure, but isn't it possible to rewrite a slug in the .htaccess and change the links from pages to the root so that no 301 redirect code is given for the page?

Basically I want to rewrite the URL: https://www.website.com/homepage to become https://www.website.com/. Would this be possible? And if so, would there be given a 301 statuscode or not if I link directly to https://www.website.com/?

Comment: You can not _redirect_ without sending a redirect status code, but you can perhaps do an internal _rewrite_. But whether that will be enough, depends on the current setup; how the URL `/homepage` gets handled to display the home page content.

Comment: How would this internal rewrite be written in the htaccess? If I change the inlinks from pages to the 'rewritten' URL there shouldn't be a redirect correct?

Comment: Basically, `RewriteRule ^$ /homepage` - that would only match on a completely empty URL path (leading slash has been stripped off at this point already), and rewrite it to `/homepage`. But whether your system will be able to _handle_ that internally rewritten URL as intended afterwards, couldn't say at this point, because we have no information about how your setup works in the first place.

Comment: I think I may have been unclear, but I actually want the /homepage to be redirected to the root, not vice versa. The developer says it's not possible, because their custom CMS just "works that way".

@CBroe I'm not sure if this would be a solution, but I just find it hard to believe that something like this wouldn't be possible.

I guess swapping the rewrites like `RewriteRule /homepage ^$` would be the way to go?

Comment: Probably still not fully clear. Do you want users that tried to access `/homepage`, to be redirected to `/`? That would be an actual external redirect then. But then you would still have to make your system _serve_ the home page content, when `/` gets requested. And if/how that will be possible, I can't tell you with the information we currently have.